# Add checkout progress bar in shopify cart.liquid page

Tags: jquery, css, e-commerce, shopify

I want to add a checkout progress bar on cart.liquid page in shopify. When a user click on add to cart on a product , I want to display a progress bar. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Did you update to the new shopify checkout system?

Answer (score 0):

New Shopify checkout system automatically displays a progress bar as soon as your customer leaves cart page to go to checkout.